# Best strategy for returning large result sets quickly

Tags: sql, linq, datatable, pagination

I've been working for the last week on trying to speed up the search results on a site. What we've been working on is moving the paging on the site to SQL. This has sped up the paging drastically, however I still need to query the entire table again to get the total count of the records in that table.

I am caching the totals and only re-running this part of the query when the user alters search parameters to speed up the paging and this works nicely. The issue we are having now is that the load on the CPU of the SQL server is increasing drasticlly and as such the performance of the paging fluctuates drastically (between 100 milliseconds and 2 seconds).

I am just wondering if it wouldn't be better to cache the entire results table on the web server and use either `DataTable.Select` or a Linq Statement to query the memory table / list? I realise this will add a large memory load to the Web Server, but we are trying to improve speed and as such it may be worth while to upgrade the Web Servers as they are also load balanced, whereas the SQL box is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this solution works really well in situations where you have paging, and want to return the total number of rows without running the query twice...

```
DECLARE @startRow INT ; SET @startrow = 50
;WITH cols
AS
(
    SELECT table_name, column_name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name, column_name) AS seq, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name DESC, column_name desc) AS totrows
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].columns
)
SELECT table_name, column_name, totrows + seq -1 as TotRows
FROM cols
WHERE seq BETWEEN @startRow AND @startRow + 49
ORDER BY seq
```

Taken from here: [SQL Server Paging - The Holy Grail](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/)

The total number of rows exists as an extra column in the resultset, but I think that's a fair tradeoff.

One modification I had to make to the solution in the article was to ensure a unique column was included in the OVER(ORDER BY) column lists.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see no-one had any suggestions, but if anyone else has this issue we eventually solved the issue by running the query to get the totals in it' own thread which is now giving us consistently higher speeds. Hooray for multi-threading!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using text search engine like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).

Keep your SQL db as the "master" - ie updatable, and use Lucene as a read-only fast search database.

I have used this strategy a few times and I can tell you fro experience that you won't believe how fast it is. It is ridiculously fast: a few milliseconds to search for and order your results ready for display on the web page.

There is a bit of work to get it all working, but it's so worth it. Also, it scales really well - because it's read only, you can easily distribute as many copies as you like across a distributed network, giving you effectively unlimited search throughput capacity.

Most large websites use it or something similar.